# Where is the Eagle component library for 0.1" breakaway headers?

Tags: eaglecad, cad

I want to put some breakaway headers into my Eagle CAD file. By that, I mean these:

[image: breakaway male headers]

Does Eagle come packaged with a library for these? If so, what is the part called, and which library is it in?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Eagle does indeed. The library you will want to look for is called `pinhead`. It has various 2.54mm (0.1") pitch pinheaders in it.

If it's not on the list, go to the Eagle control panel window, right click on `Libraries` and choose `Use all`. Then, in the schematic window, go to `Library > Update all` to update the libraries list.

Comment: +1 on this for making me laugh, wish I could give +1 to whoever named that library.

Comment: +1 for funny library names. Proteus ships with a library called ASSMANN (not for pinheads, though) :-)

Comment: Is there a female equivalent of `pinhead`?

Comment: The footprint is the same, just use the `pinhead` part and place a female header

Comment: @Bojangles that doesn't give you the correct silkscreen (i.e. instructions for assembly). The right answer is `con-lsta.lbr`. @Spookbuster

Comment: pinhead only goes up to 2xN, not 3xN or 4xN :/